# How to insert values from a subquery in merge sentence

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, merge, subquery

I want to insert into a merge statement of a stored procedure at ORACLE a value that comes from a subquery. How can I do that? This is what I design but it doesn't work.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE P_FORMULARIO
IS
BEGIN 
    MERGE INTO HT_FORMULARIO d
    USING
    (SELECT id, METODO_ID, TIPO_ID, DEPARTAMENTO_ID, EQUIPAMEINTO_ID, FECHAINICIO 
        FROM ODS_FORMULARIO) o
    ON  (d.ID_CAMPO = o.id)
    WHEN MATCHED THEN
        UPDATE SET d.SK_METODO_MUEST = o.METODO_ID,
        d.SK_TIPO_MUESTRA = o.TIPO_ID,
        d.SK_DEPARTAMENTO = o.DEPARTAMENTO_ID,
        d.SK_EQUIPAMIENTO = o.EQUIPAMEINTO_ID
    WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
        INSERT (ID_CAMPO, SK_METODO_MUEST, SK_TIPO_MUESTRA, SK_DEPARTAMENTO, SK_EQUIPAMIENTO)
        VALUES (o.id, o.METODO_ID, o.TIPO_ID,o.DEPARTAMENTO_ID, o.EQUIPAMEINTO_ID, 
            (select SK_FECHA from dt_fecha where mes = MONTH( o.FECHAINICIO) and anio = YEAR(o.FECHAINICIO));
    COMMIT;
END P_EQUIPAMIENTO;
```

I don't know if that is possible, thanks for the help.

Comment: it is possible but can tell us what is the error that you are getting? it is difficult to debug your code when we dont have all the tables that you are using in this query. but if you tell me the error and the line number that you are recieving the error I might be able to help.

Comment: "...but I doesn't work." Please, do not use such general description, it provides exactly no information about actual issue. Add an error text or describe what is wrong with your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some things wrong in your procedure

- The `subselect` below the insert does not make any sense, as you have only five fields in the insert clause and five values in the `values` section.
- You are getting all the records from `ODS_FORMULARIO` that are matching with the target table `HT_FORMULARIO` based on the `ID`, then use that part to get the values of year and month there.
- It is not clear whether you want to do with `year` and `month`. Those are java in-build funtions, not SQL.
- The insert misses a field.

Your functions don't work in SQL:

```
SQL> select month(sysdate) from dual ;
select month(sysdate) from dual
       *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00904: "MONTH": invalid identifier

SQL> select year(sysdate) from dual ;
select year(sysdate) from dual
       *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00904: "YEAR": invalid identifier
```

Keep in mind the way to get this year and month from your `dt_fecha` table, some options you might have for that are:

```
SQL> select to_char(sysdate,'Month') from dual ;

TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'MONTH')
------------------------------------
October

SQL> select to_char(sysdate,'YYYY') from dual ;

TO_C
----
2021

SQL> select extract(month from sysdate) from dual ;

EXTRACT(MONTHFROMSYSDATE)
-------------------------
                       10

SQL>  select extract(year from sysdate) from dual ;

EXTRACT(YEARFROMSYSDATE)
------------------------
                    2021
```

Then you have the column `MES` in the table `DT_FECHA`. If you have the month store with the name, you need to use `NLS_LANGUAGE` to get the right name according to your language. Example, in German

```
SQL> select TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'fmDay, DD Month YYYY', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=''GERMAN''') from dual;

TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'FMDAY,DDMONTHYYYY','NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=''GERMAN''')
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Samstag, 16 Oktober 2021
```

Having say that, you want to refactor the merge and use a join in the source part of the statement to get there the `sk_fecha` value.

**Important: Remember that I am assuming some things, like the month is stored in Spanish but not in uppercase. If it is stored in uppercase, use the function `upper` before `to_char`. If it is in another language, use the proper `nls_language`. If the month is stored as a number, then you can use `to_char` with `'MM'` or `extract` as in my example above**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE P_FORMULARIO
IS
begin 
    MERGE INTO HT_FORMULARIO d
    USING
    (SELECT 
       odsf.id, 
       odsf.METODO_ID, 
       odsf.TIPO_ID, 
       odsf.DEPARTAMENTO_ID, 
       odsf.EQUIPAMEINTO_ID, 
       odsf.FECHAINICIO, 
       to_char(odsf.FECHAINICIO,'Month', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=''SPANISH''') as Month, 
       to_char(odsf.FECHAINICIO,'YYYY') as Year , 
       dtf.sk_fecha 
        FROM ODS_FORMULARIO odsf 
                    join dt_fecha dft on dtf.mes = odsf.mes and dtf.anio = odsf.year ) o
    ON  (d.ID_CAMPO = o.id)
    WHEN MATCHED THEN
        UPDATE SET d.SK_METODO_MUEST = o.METODO_ID,
        d.SK_TIPO_MUESTRA = o.TIPO_ID,
        d.SK_DEPARTAMENTO = o.DEPARTAMENTO_ID,
        d.SK_EQUIPAMIENTO = o.EQUIPAMEINTO_ID
    WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
        INSERT (ID_CAMPO, SK_METODO_MUEST, SK_TIPO_MUESTRA, SK_DEPARTAMENTO, SK_EQUIPAMIENTO , --a field here is missing--)
        VALUES (o.id, o.METODO_ID, o.TIPO_ID,o.DEPARTAMENTO_ID, o.EQUIPAMEINTO_ID, o.SK_FECHA );
    COMMIT;
END P_EQUIPAMIENTO;
```